# How can I have a class derived from a class known at runtime implementing an interface known at compilation

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I think I'd be easier to just write down my pseudo-class declaration.

Basically, I want something like

```
public class DatabaseControlsDAL<T> : T, IDatabaseControlsDAL where T : IBaseDAL
{
   public int myMethod()
   {
      return somePublicPropertyInTheIBaseDALInterface;
   }
}
```

But it won't work :(

Any help welcome !

Comment: does your class have a `T` or a list of `T` somewhere in it?

Comment: Nope. `T : IBaseDAL` only provides a couple of helper function meant to be overriden in a test environment.

Comment: You can't inherit `T`.  This won't work at all.

Comment: You cannot derive from the generic parameter

Comment: why do you need to do this? if T is an IBaseDAL, why not just pin that?

Comment: Well actually the T value is known through dependency injection, but I'd like to have my DAL classes inherit from it, instead of instanciating it.

Comment: Why do you need to inherit from `T`?

Comment: Considering the title of your question only, yes. What you are looking for is called "dependency injection" or "inversion of control". There are a lot of libraries that do this.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use "composition" rather than "inheritance". Try going down that path.

Comment: You'd need something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659728/creating-c-sharp-classes-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't a *run-time* feature, thus giving a generic argument won't be a *run-time issue*.

In the other hand, how would a class inherit what will be only known at run-time? Think C# is a strongly-typed language.

If B inherits A, but A is "unknown", then, until run-time, B won't be of type A. This defeats both the point of inheritance and polymorphism.

Conclusion: if you don't provide a background in order to let us define a better solution (well, an existing solution!), you'll get this answer: **you can't achieve what you're looking for in C#**.